# How to control the 10 records previewed in a lookup control?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I am working with activities and the fields, to, from, etc.
We have created custom views dynamically in order to make the selection easier. That is fine

My problem is... when you push the icon to search contacts... Is it possible add and order a custom list for the previewed 10 records?

To avoid the user clicking on the "Look up More records", select the custom view and add the "TO" record?

Comment: Did you try this?

Answer (score 1):

Custom views always gives the power for users to switch & select the records. If you cannot solve it by user training, then implement some form save (or pre-update plugin) validations to iterate through the party list & alert them when things are not in place.

Otherwise - I used to do this `addPreSearch` and `addCustomFilter` technique all the time. [Read more](https://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2016/03/24/filtering-partylist-fields-with-javascript-addpresearch/)

```
function FilterPartyList() {
    var Regarding = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("regardingobjectid").getValue();
//checking if regarding fields is empty before we apply the filter
    if (Regarding != null) {
        Xrm.Page.getControl("requiredattendees").addPreSearch(Filter);
    }
}

function Filter() {

    var RegardingValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("regardingobjectid").getValue();

    //if Regarding has a value, proceed
    if (RegardingValue != null) {
        //used to retrieve Name of the Account held in the Regarding field
        var RegardingTextValue = RegardingValue[0].name;
        //GUID used in filter
        var RegardingID = RegardingValue[0].id;

        var plist_filter = "<filter type='and'>" + "<condition attribute='parentcustomerid' operator='eq' name='" + RegardingTextValue + "' value='" + RegardingID + "' />" + "</filter>";
        Xrm.Page.getControl("optionalattendees").addCustomFilter(plist_filter, "contact");

    }
}
```